# Calculating Binomial coefficients using dynamic programming

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming

I wrote this code to find Binomial coefficients <sub>n</sub>C<sub>k</sub>:

```
# include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int c[20][20];
void initialize()
{
    for(int i=0;i<20;i++) 
        for(int j=i;j<20;j++)
            c[i][j]=-1;
}
int binomCoeff(int n,int k)
{
    if(k==0||k==n) return 1;
    if(c[n][k]!=-1)
        return c[n][k];
    return c[n][k] =  binomCoeff(n-1,k-1) + binomCoeff(n-1,k);
}

int main()
{
    initialize();
    cout<<binomCoeff(4,2)<<endl;
}
```

I'm new to dynamic programming, so I can't find the error.

Comment: Do you got any error message?

Answer (score 1):

You are using the second index for k (less or equal to n) but initialize only bigger indexes

```
for(int j=  0  ;j<20;j++)
or
for(int j=  0  ;   j <= i  ;j++)
```

Note that this mistake would be discovered during step-by-step debugging. Why did you ignore such approach?

P.S. Method used here is `memoization` - "top-down" kind of dynamic programming. You can also implement "bottom-up" dynamic programming as exercise - fill table in order and get the last cell result.

Comment: the bottom up DP solution can be found at: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-programming-set-9-binomial-coefficient/

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sample code that shows the use of both top-down and bottom-up DP. (A small DP table size (V=8) was chosen for printing purposes, a much larger table size is recommended.)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

#define V 8
int memo[V][V]; //DP table

int min(int a, int b) {return (a < b) ? a : b;}

void print_table(int memo[V][V])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < V; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < V; ++j)
        {
            printf(" %2d", memo[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int binomial_coeffs1(int n, int k)
{
    // top-down DP
    if (k == 0 || k == n) return 1;
    if (memo[n][k] != -1) return memo[n][k];
    return memo[n][k] = binomial_coeffs1(n-1, k-1) + binomial_coeffs1(n-1, k);
}

int binomial_coeffs2(int n, int k)
{
    // bottom-up DP
    for (int i = 0; i <= n; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j <= min(i, k); ++j)
        {
            if (j == 0 || j == i)
            {
                memo[i][j] = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                memo[i][j] = memo[i-1][j-1] + memo[i-1][j]; 
            }
        }
    }
    return memo[n][k];
}


int main()
{
    int n = 5, k = 2;

    printf("Top-down DP:\n");
    memset(memo, -1, sizeof(memo));
    int nCk1 = binomial_coeffs1(n, k);
    print_table(memo);
    printf("C(n=%d, k=%d): %d\n", n, k, nCk1);

    printf("Bottom-up DP:\n");
    memset(memo, -1, sizeof(memo));
    int nCk2 = binomial_coeffs2(n, k);
    print_table(memo);
    printf("C(n=%d, k=%d): %d\n", n, k, nCk2);

    return 0;
}
```

The above code is based on the recursion for binomial coefficients with overlapping sub-problems:

```
C(n,0) = C(n,n) = 1
C(n,k) = C(n-1, k-1) + C(n-1, k)
```

You can compile the above code as follows:

```
>>> g++ <filename>.cpp --std=c++11 -Wall -o test
>>> ./test
```